# XSS vulnerabililty script tags encoding

Tags: security, xss

I have a security scan that reports a XSS vulnerabililty when setting an http parameter to the following value.   It renders a script tag

```
'1234'"/><img%20src%3D%26%23x6a;%26%23x61;%26%23x76;%26%23x61;%26%23x73;%26%23x63;%26%23x72;%26%23x69;%26%23x70;%
26%23x74;%26%23x3a;alert%26%23x28;5846%26%23x29;>'
```

it doesn't look like html encoding or url encoding, what kind of encoding is it for the script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by “HTTP parameter” you mean an URL parameter, then the URL encoded octets `%hh` get decoded to:

```
'1234'"/><img src=&#x6a;&#x61;&#x76;&#x61;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3a;alert&#x28;5846&#x29;>'
```

And if that value gets printed into a context where it’s interpreted as HTML, the character references `&#xhh;` in the attribute value get decoded to:

```
'1234'"/><img src=javascript:alert(5846)>'
```